# Why am i getting client = discord.client() TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, discord

```
    import discord

    client = discord.client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("joe mama!!!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content == 'joe':
        await message.channel.send('Yo mama so fat, when she skips a meal, the stock market drops.')

client.run('...')
```

When i click run it says

client = discord.client()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I did install discord.py

Comment: Welcome 
to SO! Please show the full stack trace, not just the error message.

Answer (score -1):

Your code indent seems to be messed up, but i assume thats just something that happened when you copied the code. Like shown here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html
I assume the issue is, that `Client` needs to be spelled with capital C.
Hope this helps. If something alike occurs again, you can look at example code and you'll find the solution way quicker ;).